# display details using entity framework

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I want to display details of a selected item from a combo box in wpf using entity framework. But my code below only displays the first entry from database no matter what item is selected.

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Entities c = new Entities())
        {
            string sFirst = c.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault().First.ToString();
            string sLast = c.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefault().Last.ToString();

            txtFirst.Text = sFirst;
            txtSecond.Text = sLast;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing up stuffs.

I believe what you actually want is the item within the combox.
Try this code:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
        if (comboBox != null)
        {
            var item = comboBox.SelectedItem as EntityType;
            //EntityType == the table you are loading into combobox (I guess it supposed to be UserProfile)
            if (item != null)
            {
                txtFirst.Text = item.First.ToString();
                txtSecond.Text = item.Last.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not filtering the data from the database... there is no `where` clause that specifies the selected item. I have no idea on the structure of your data but try something like this:

```
using (Entities c = new Entities())
{
    string sFirst = c.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.Id == selectedItemId).First().First.ToString();
    string sLast = c.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.Id == selectedItemId).First().Last.ToString();

    txtFirst.Text = sFirst;
    txtSecond.Text = sLast;
}
```

Furthermore, there is no point in using `FirstOrDefault()` if you are not going to check whether the result is `null` or not.